# Errors in systemd service when the command requires realtime midi and alsa thread scheduling

Tags: systemd, services

I have this service unit file:

```
Type=simple
User=meghdad
ExecStart=/etc/startpianoteq.sh


[Unit]
Description=Pianoteq using a preset

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This service would run a program called Pianoteq that requires realtime access to audio and midi threads. However, after running the service, I get errors that say:'
"Midi thread could not acquire real-time scheduling, error 1 -- Operation not permitted"

The script is a oneliner and makes a call to the Pianoteq executable.

Note that I can run the script manually just fine. So it must be a config issue.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer by asking on the #archlinux channel.

I needed to add the following to the service section of the service definition file:

```
LimitRTPRIO=infinity
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
LimitRTTIME=infinity
```

[Further info here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22050297/5088769)